# Java Stax for Complex / Large XML

Tags: java, xml, stax

I have an XML file that is 4.2 GB! Obviously parsing the entire DOM is not practical. I have been looking at SAX and STAX to accomplish parsing this gigantic XML file. However all the examples I've seen are simple. The XML file I am dealing with has nested on nested on nested. There are areas where it goes 10+ levels.

I found this tutorial but not sure if its a viable solution.

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/parsing-xml-using-dom-sax-and-stax-parser-in-java.html (botton example using STAX)

I'm not really sure how to handle nested objects.

I have created Java objects to mimic the structure of the XML. Here are a few, too many to display.

Record.java

```
public class Record implements Serializable {

    String uid;
    StaticData staticData;
    DynamicData dynamicData;
}
```

Summary.java

```
public class Summary {

    EWUID ewuid;
    PubInfo pubInfo;
    Titles titles;
    Names names;
    DocTypes docTypes;
    Publishers publishers;
}
```

EWUID.java

```
public class EWUID {

    String collId;
    String edition;
}
```

PubInfo.java

```
public class PubInfo {

    String coverDate;
    String hasAbstract;
    String issue;
    String pubMonth;
    String pubType;
    String pubYear;
    String sortDate;
    String volume;
}
```

This is the code I've come up with so far.

```
public class TRWOSParser {

    XMLEventReader eventReader;
    XMLInputFactory inputFactory;
    InputStream inputStream;

    public TRWOSParser(String file) throws FileNotFoundException, XMLStreamException {
        inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        eventReader = inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(inputStream);
    }

    public void parse() throws XMLStreamException{

        while (eventReader.hasNext()) {
            XMLEvent event = eventReader.nextEvent();

            if (event.isStartElement()) {
                StartElement startElement = event.asStartElement();
                if (startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("record")) {
                    Record record = new Record();
                    Iterator<Attribute> attributes = startElement.getAttributes();
                    while (attributes.hasNext()) {
                        Attribute attribute = attributes.next();
                        if (attribute.getName().toString().equals("UID")) {
                            System.out.println("UID: " + attribute.getValue());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update:

The data in the XML is licensed so I cannot show the full file. This is a very very small segment in which I have scrambled the data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<records>
    <REC>
        <UID>WOS:000310438600004</UID>
        <static_data>
            <summary>
                <EWUID>
                    <WUID coll_id="WOS" />
                    <edition value="WOS.SCI" />
                </EWUID>
                <pub_info coverdate="NOV 2012" has_abstract="N" issue="5" pubmonth="NOV" pubtype="Journal" pubyear="2012" sortdate="2012-11-01" vol="188">
                    <page begin="1662" end="1663" page_count="2">1662-1663</page>
                </pub_info>
                <titles count="6">
                    <title type="source">JOURNAL OF UROLOGY</title>
                    <title type="source_abbrev">J UROLOGY</title>
                    <title type="abbrev_iso">J. Urol.</title>
                    <title type="abbrev_11">J UROL</title>
                    <title type="abbrev_29">J UROL</title>
                    <title type="item">Something something</title>
                </titles>
                <names count="1">
                    <name addr_no="1 2 3" reprint="Y" role="author" seq_no="1">
                        <display_name>John Doe</display_name>
                        <full_name>John Doe</full_name>
                        <wos_standard>Doe, John</wos_standard>
                        <first_name>John</first_name>
                        <last_name>Doe</last_name>
                    </name>
                </names>
                <doctypes count="1">
                    <doctype>Editorial Material</doctype>
                </doctypes>
                <publishers>
                    <publisher>
                        <address_spec addr_no="1">
                            <full_address>360 PARK AVE SOUTH, NEW YORK, NY 10010-1710 USA</full_address>
                            <city>NEW YORK</city>
                        </address_spec>
                        <names count="1">
                            <name addr_no="1" role="publisher" seq_no="1">
                                <display_name>ELSEVIER SCIENCE INC</display_name>
                                <full_name>ELSEVIER SCIENCE INC</full_name>
                            </name>
                        </names>
                    </publisher>
                </publishers>
            </summary>
        </static_data>
    </REC>
</records>
```

Comment: Couple questions:  Do you have a schema for this file, and is there an identifiable level of maximum repetition?  It goes several levels deep -- that's fine, but does it have an identifiable from which it be safe to parse the whole subtree at once?

Comment: I've ask for the XSD but for the moment I don't have one. I'm not entirely sure how deep it can go, the most I've seen thus far is 11.

Comment: Your problem isn't the level of nesting, it's the rate of repetition.  At which level does it get repetitive enough that you could start handling the subtrees all at once?

Comment: There is a ton of repetition even early on.

Comment: I updated the question added a very small sample set with scrambled data. I can't show the file since the data is licensed.

Comment: Oh, that's super easy.  I'm assuming your REC record just repeats a few million times.  Use the code sample below and set the maxBranch to 1

Comment: You haven't actually said what you want to do with the data: what is the desired output of your program?

Comment: I need to insert select fields into a database

Comment: Have we helped you out -- are you still stuck?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I ended up using dom4j, api seemed much easier to work with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar solution to lscoughlin's answer is to use DOM4J which has mechanims to deal with this scenario: http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/

In my opionin it is more straight forward and easier to follow. It might not support namespaces, though.

Comment: I ended up using dom4j. The API is very easy to work with and solved my issue of loading the entire DOM into memory

Comment: @greyfox I also need to use dom4j. During the test code process is getting terminated, and I have no idea why it is happening. I am using XPath navigation. Can you share more details about it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm making two assumptions 1) that there is an early level of repetition, and 2) that you can do something meaningful with a partial document.

Let's assume you can move some level of nesting in, and then handle the document multiple times, removing the nodes at the working level each time you "handle" the document.  This means that only a single working subtree will be in memory at any given time.

Here's a working code snippet:

```
package bigparse;

import static javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS;
import static javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamConstants.END_DOCUMENT;
import static javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT;
import static javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamConstants.START_DOCUMENT;
import static javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class BigParse {

    public static void main(String... args) {

        XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        try {

            XMLStreamReader streamReader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader("src/main/resources/test.xml"));
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();
            Element rootElement = null;
            Element currentElement = null;

            int branchLevel = 0;
            int maxBranchLevel = 1;

            while (streamReader.hasNext()) {
                int event = streamReader.next();
                switch (event) {
                case START_DOCUMENT:
                    continue;
                case START_ELEMENT:

                    if (branchLevel < maxBranchLevel) {
                        Element workingElement = readElementOnly(streamReader, document);

                        if (rootElement == null) {
                            document.appendChild(workingElement);
                            rootElement = document.getDocumentElement();
                            currentElement = rootElement;
                        } else {
                            currentElement.appendChild(workingElement);
                            currentElement = workingElement;
                        }

                        branchLevel++;
                    } else {

                        workingLoop(streamReader, document, currentElement);

                    }

                    continue;
                case CHARACTERS:
                    currentElement.setTextContent(streamReader.getText());
                    continue;

                case END_ELEMENT:
                    if (currentElement != rootElement) {
                        currentElement = (Element) currentElement.getParentNode();
                        branchLevel--;
                    }

                    continue;

                case END_DOCUMENT:
                    break;
                }

            }

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException
                | FileNotFoundException
                | XMLStreamException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

    private static Element readElementOnly(XMLStreamReader streamReader, Document document) {

        Element workingElement = document.createElement(streamReader.getLocalName());

        for (int attributeIndex = 0; attributeIndex < streamReader.getAttributeCount(); attributeIndex++) {
            workingElement.setAttribute(
                    streamReader.getAttributeLocalName(attributeIndex),
                    streamReader.getAttributeValue(attributeIndex));

        }
        return workingElement;
    }

    private static void workingLoop(final XMLStreamReader streamReader, final Document document, final Element fragmentRoot)
            throws XMLStreamException {

        Element startElement = readElementOnly(streamReader, document);
        fragmentRoot.appendChild(startElement);

        Element currentElement = startElement;

        while (streamReader.hasNext()) {
            int event = streamReader.next();
            switch (event) {
            case START_DOCUMENT:
                continue;
            case START_ELEMENT:

                Element workingElement = readElementOnly(streamReader, document);
                currentElement.appendChild(workingElement);
                currentElement = workingElement;

                continue;
            case CHARACTERS:
                currentElement.setTextContent(streamReader.getText());
                continue;

            case END_ELEMENT:
                if (currentElement != startElement) {
                    currentElement = (Element) currentElement.getParentNode();
                    continue;

                } else {

                    handleDocument(document, startElement);

                    fragmentRoot.removeChild(startElement);
                    startElement = null;
                    return;
                }

            }

        }

    }

    // THIS FUNCTION DOES SOMETHING MEANINFUL
    private static void handleDocument(Document document, Element startElement) {

        System.out.println(stringify(document));
    }

    private static String stringify(Document document) {

        try {
            Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);

            transformer.transform(source, result);

            String xmlString = result.getWriter().toString();
            return xmlString;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT:  I made an incredibly silly mistake.  It's fixed now.  It's working but imperfect -- should be enough to lead you in a useful direction.**

Comment: I had some issues getting this to work, and the suggestion of dom4j looked like a nicer API, but I did +1 for level of detail, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Consider using an XSLT 3.0 streaming transformation of the form:

```
<xsl:template name="main">
  <xsl:stream href="bigInput.xml">
    <xsl:for-each select="copy-of(/records/REC)">
      <!-- process one record -->
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:stream>
</xsl:template>
```

You can process this using Saxon-EE 9.6.

The "process one record" logic could use the Saxon SQL extension, or it could invoke an extension function: the context node will be a REC element with its contained tree, fully navigable within the subtree, but with no ability to navigate outside the REC element currently being processed.

Comment: No, sorry. It's bleeding edge stuff, still a W3C working draft, so you're a bit on your own. Dimitre Novatchev has a number of XSLT 3.0 tutorials at http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/xslt-3-0-whats-new-part1?gclid=CLajm6T4jscCFSb3wgodfkYN1A, but I'm not sure he covers streaming. There are a number of examples of xsl:stream in the spec at http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#stream-examples, and the copy-of() function is described at http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#func-copy-of